# Allow Client to Change Files, Add Folders *Not in FTP*

Tags: web-applications

I have a weird requirement. Is there a way to allow someone the ability to create folders, edit files, add files on a server without using a FTP client. This would ideally be browser based and under one admin sesssion.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a webdav server is an alternative.

Comment: This is my thought as well, but you'd want to know the client's OS. WebDAV is a pain in the ass on XP for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write a web app to do it.  Your success will vary based on the OS of the said server, the development language, and the quality of the developers.  See [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) for general file uploading rules.  The other file upload operations depend heavily on what language and system.  For example, on Windows in ASP.NET you could make the changes using the classes in the [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx), [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)).